# How to combine hyper link with text/logo in the given code?

Tags: hyperlink

Hi how could I modify the following code so that when I click say the github logo or Bob it takes me to a link? I tried a few things but couldn't get it to work. Many thanks :)

```
\begin{center}
    \textbf{\Huge Bob} \\ \vspace{5pt}
    \small \faPhone* \texttt{+64 124} \hspace{1pt} $|$
    \hspace{1pt} \faEnvelope \hspace{2pt} \texttt{bob_b@hotmail.co.nz} \hspace{1pt} $|$ 
    \hspace{1pt} \faGithub\hspace{2pt} \texttt{bob} \hspace{1pt} $|$
    \hspace{1pt} \faLinkedin \hspace{2pt}\texttt{bob} $|$
    \hspace{1pt} \faMapMarker* \hspace{2pt}\texttt{Auckland, NZ}
    %\href{http://www.overleaf.com}
    \\ \vspace{-3pt}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `\href` from `hyperref` package to provide destination links like this:

```
\href{https://github.com}{\faGithub} \hspace{2pt} 
\href{https://github.com}{\texttt{bob}}
```

Comment: Ahh my mistake was that I tried using /href on the icon/text in the same line! Your solution however works so cheers!